# Hibernate / Spring / JPA - How to insert with a select subquery

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Given this hypothetical table structure:

```
person
id | reference | name

book
id | name | person_id
```

And this class structure

```
@Entity(name = "book")
public class Book {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  @Column(name = "id")
  Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  String name;

  // WHAT GOES HERE?
  UUID personReference;

  ...
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {
}
```

How would one insert the `book` row while using a select the `person.id` using the `personReference` field on the `Book` class. A query that would usually look like this:

```
insert into book (name, person_id)
values (?, (select id from person p where p.reference = ?))
```

Is this something that is possible through annotations or should I look to just implement a query?

Comment: Do you have a @Entity class for Person ?

Comment: @NiceBooks I do not. I know this is possible with nested objects but I would like to keep my models separate. Is there a way if a Person `@Entity` existed?

Answer (score -1):

If Person is not mapped as an entity, you can use native SQL queries.

I'm not sure if this is an error, but the mapping should be:

```
@Column(name="person_id")
UUID personReference;
```

If that's a valid native SQL query, you can do the insert using it:

```
@Modifying
@Query(nativeQuery=true, value="insert into book (name, person_id) values (?1, (select id from person p where p.reference = ?2))")
public int insert(String name, String reference);
```

Your question doesn't contain enough info to figure out if you can map `Person` as an entity. If that's the case, [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-manytoone-association-using-a-non-primary-key-column/) might help you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but hibernate seems to have a very inconsistent way of ordering the mapped values. My actual classes have a lot more fields than the ones I created as an example so I found it extremely irritating having to use trial and error to get the input order correct and wouldn't want to go through it again if I added a new field. In this case I would rather just implement the repository with a static insert query where I can use named parameters.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with inconsistent order of the mapped values. You should be able to use named parameters with native queries: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-query-parameters

Comment: I mean that you must run the insert with debug logging enabled to know what order the `?` are populated. I had seen the approach you linked but that would not be using an annotation approach. I have decided because of this kerfuffle that I'd rather use my usual approach with a custom `Repository` implementation and using the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` to execute and populate the parameters e.g. `jdbcTemplate.update(insertQuery, new MapSqlParameterSource("person_reference", personReference));`

Comment: Just curious at this point. Aren't parameters populated in the order they appear in the method? You can also use `?1`, `?2`, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate is an implementation of the **Java Persistence API** (JPA) which is a Java specific **Object Relational Model** (ORM). The purpose of ORMs is to handle sql rows as objects & it includes relations as well.

```
@Entity
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    Long id;

    String name;

    // relational mapping
    @ManyToOne // an author can write multiple books. but a book has a single author
    Person author; // an author is a Person not an UUID
}
```

But to store Person object in your db, you need to have a Person Entity as well.

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    long id; // primitive types can be primary keys too

    String name;

}
```

I strongly advise to learn the basics of JPA ([Specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.pdf))

Then, in your `@Repository` classes (Spring specific):

```
@Repository
public BookRepository implements CrudRepository<Book,Long> {    

}

@Repository 
public PersonRepository implements CrudRepository<Book,Long> {

}
```

Finally, in your `@Service` class (Spring specific):

```
@Service
public class BookService {

    
    PersonRepository personRepo;
    BookRepository bookRepo;

    public BookService(PersonRepository personRepo, BookRepository bookRepo) {
        this.personRepo = personRepo;
        this.bookRepo = bookRepo;
    }

    public void setBookAuthor(Book book, Person author) {
        book.setAuthor(author);
        bookRepo.save(book);
    }

    public void setBookAuthor(long bookId, long personId) {
        Book book = bookRepo.findById(bookId);
        Person author = userRepo.findById(personId);
        setBookAuthor(book, author);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that but it's not quite what I'm looking for. I would like to achieve this without having to create a nested model hierarchy. As in I would like `Book` and `Person` classes to not have to include each other, only reference each other where necessary. I have decided that it isn't worth the time to fiddle and went with a custom `Repository` implementation using the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` to manually execute the queries I need and map the fields to the columns. e.g. `jdbcTemplate.update(insertQuery, new MapSqlParameterSource("person_reference", personReference));`